# How can I modify a macro to copy entire sheet and then paste values only instead of pasting everything?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a macro that others helped me build that copies everything in the active worksheet, creates a new file, pastes everything, and then saves that as a csv file. However, I now need to modify it to paste values rather than paste everything, and I'm unsure what the right way to do that is since I'm not very familiar with VBA. Here was my original code in its entirety:

```
 Sub ExportCSV()

   Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = ActiveSheet

   Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   
   With wbNew
       Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1")
       ws.Rows.Copy
       wsNew.Paste
       .SaveAs Filename:="C:\" & ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
       
   End With
   Windows(ws.Name & ".csv").Activate
   ActiveWindow.Close
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I know that I need to modify the line `wsNew.Paste`, and I've tried each of the following replacements for that line, but it's probably pretty obvious that I'm on a complete fishing expedition as to what the right syntax might be:

```
 wsNew.Paste xlValues
 wsNew.Paste xlPasteValues
 wsNew.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 wsNew.PasteSpecial xlValues
 wsNew.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
 wsNew.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 wsNew.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

None of these work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `ActiveSheet` a worksheet in `ThisWorkbook` (the workbook containing this code)?

Comment: yes, `ActiveSheet` is a worksheet in `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `Range` portion; it's [`Range.PasteSpecial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial), not `Worksheet.PasteSpecial`.

```
wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Question, though, why do I need to specify the range here when I didn't need to when it was pasting everything? The original code did work; it just didn't paste values alone.

Comment: Because there *is* a [`Worksheet.Paste`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.paste) method, but it pastes everything and does not have the option to paste only values. Though to be honest, not sure why you need to paste values if you're saving as a csv.

Comment: Huh, ok, thanks. I needed to paste values because when I used `=INDEX(...)` to fill in values from elsewhere, that was saved as all #N/A values in the csv file. I was surprised by that behavior, too.